# Is there a way to write a parallel chemical reaction like this one?

Tags: chemistry, parallel, chemformula

Im using the package chemformula, but I can't find a way to write something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, @Eduardo Romero. Please, read about [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)s. Here, a good and also a polite practice is to present (when possible) what you have already tried.

Comment: `chemfig` can do it

Answer (score 8):

With use of `chemfig` and `mhchem` packages, chem formulas arein `\llap` (left) and `rlap` (right) commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}  % or figure[ht]\centering
\schemestart
    \llap{\ce{C2H5OH}}\arrow{->[\color{teal}\ce{ZnO}][]}[30]          \rlap{\ce{C2H4 + H2O}} 
                      \arrow(@c1--C){->[][\color{teal}\ce{Cu}]}[-30]  \rlap{\ce{C2H4O + H2}}
\schemestop
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One of a best suggestion...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, thank you very much!

Comment: Thank u so much!!!

Answer (score 6):

with chemfig and chemformula

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\ch{C2H5OH}
\arrow(eth.mid east--.mid west){->[ \color{green!80!black}\scriptsize\ch{ZnO} ]}[10]
\ch{C2H4 + H2O}
\arrow(@eth.mid east--.mid west){->[][ \color{green!80!black}\scriptsize\ch{Cu} ]}[-10]
\ch{C2H4O + H2}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u, it looks really nice

Answer (score 3):

Package [chemformula](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/chemformula/chemformula-manual.pdf) doesn't seem to be concerned with spatial chemistry. No such example is presented. On the other hand, [chemfig](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) does present many spatial chemistry compounds.

`Chemformula` presents in section 7.2 some examples using more than on line and in section 12 some example inside the math environment `align`. I reproduced both below.

A possible workaround if you don't want to swap packages (or can't) is using TikZ wherever needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% 7.2. Option Input
\ch{H2O +}\textcolor{red}{\ch{H2SO4}}\ch{-> H3O+ + HSO4-} \par
2 \ch{H2O +}\ch[subscript-vshift=2pt]{H2SO4}\ch{-> H3O+ + HSO4-}
% 12. Usage In Math Equations
\begin{align}
  \ch{
    H2O & ->[a] H2SO4 \\
    Cl2 & ->[x][y] CH4
  }
\end{align}
% Possible workaround with TikZ
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (0,0) coordinate(A) node[left]{\ch{H2O +}\textcolor{red}{\ch{H2SO4}}} -- 
    ++(1,1) node[right]{\ch{H3O+ + HSO4-}};
  \draw[->] (A) -- 
    ++(1,-1) node[right]{\ch{H3O+ + HSO4-}};;
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, that's a great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more colorful solution

```
\documentclass[margin={2mm 4mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
%
\chemfig{C_2H_5O@{z}H}
%
\arrow(@{z}--){0}[60,.1]\chemfig{-[:60,1,,,red,thick]@{y}}
\arrow(@{y}--){->[\chemfig{\textcolor{blue}{ZnO}}]}[0,1.5,,,red,thick,shorten <=-10pt]
%
\chemfig{C_2H_4} \+ \chemfig{H_2O}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\arrow(@{z}--){0}[300,.1]\chemfig{-[:300,1,,,blue,thick]@{x}}
\arrow(@{x}--){->[\chemfig{\textcolor{red}{Cu}}]}[0,1.5,,blue,thick,shorten <=-10pt]
%
\chemfig{C_2H_4O} \+ \chemfig{H_2}
%
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks really good , I appreciate it!